# How to clone a BitBucket repository with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

***I am using RedHat Linux***

1. I have created a repository in `BitBucket` say **Demo** and I have
   some `HTML` code into that.
2. I have installed `Jenkins` on my system.

What I am trying to do is clone the `BitBucket` repository with `Jenkins` so that I will be able to build the project.

**Steps what I am following is**

1. Creating a new Job In `Jenkins`.
2. Giving a description of the project
3. In the **Source Code Management** tab selecting `git` and `Jenkins` ask for repository URL, and I am giving this URL.
   [image]

but `Jenkins` throwing an error saying:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git
>   ls-remote -h git clone
>   https://UserName@bitbucket.org/UserName/java-script.git HEAD

I spent around 3 days and could not configure this instead learned a lot about `Jenkins`.
I have also tried the `BitBucket` plug-in for `Jenkins` that also was not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure jenkins with bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074395/how-to-configure-jenkins-with-bitbucket)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For Jenkins 1.5 or greater( till 1.6)

The error you are getting because in the global configuration of Jenkins, the git path is not correct/or not inserted.

That's why Jenkins is unable to run the git command.

Please go to `Manage Jenkins-> Configure System Settings`. Check for git section and add correct path.

[image]
Its already seems that you have removed the Git Clone from the URL provided by Bitbucket.

**Update**:

> For Jenkins 2.0 or above

You can find this setting under **Global tool configuration**.

Comment: correct path. in the sense the Bitbucket path which I have shown in the above scree

Comment: no not the bitbucket path. i am talking about the path where git is installed on your system. for ex. my machine is linux(centos 6.5) and in my case git is installed at /usr/local/bin/git. or if its windows it might be C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

Comment: the bitbucket path is correct. https://DrunkenCooder@bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/java-script.git

Comment: Sorry bro i have not installed git in my system. I'll just do that. but, why do we need git since we are pulling the code from Bitbucket ?

Comment: Jenkins doesn't comes with GIT,So we have to install GIT and have to tell Jenkins about GIT path so that Jenkins can run GIT commands at backend. Hope this has answered your question.

Comment: After installing git and after giving the path I am getting this error

Comment: Could not init /tmp/hudson4551896643487321839tmp

Comment: as u have mention I have specified the git executable path /usr/bin/git . now I have getting this error  "Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git3516666924035828487.credentials" returned status code 129:
stdout:
stderr: error: unknown option `local'
usage: git config [options]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    -f, --file <FILE>     use given config file

Comment: instead of `Configure System Settings` in Jenkins 2.27 it's called `Global Tool Configuration`

Comment: @BillK Yes you are right, Now from Jenkins 2 its defined under Global Tool Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "git clone" keywords and it should work :)

Jenkins only need the http URL:

https://UserName@bitbucket.org/UserName/java-script.git

Comment: When I am giving the whole URL                                                                 git clone https://DrunkenCooder@bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/java-script.git , it throws this "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h git clone https://DrunkenCooder@bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/java-script.git HEAD "

Comment: When I am giving only URL https://DrunkenCooder@bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/java-script.git , it throws this " Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://DrunkenCooder@bitbucket.org/DrunkenCooder/java-script.git HEAD"

Comment: On your Jenkins server, are you able to run the git clone http//... command?

Answer (score -1):

This is because private key is not establishing to GIT through Jenkins.

So create credentials:

1. go to Jenkin Configure==>Source Code Management==>Add==>Jenkins;
2. select Domain as global;
3. select Kind 'SSH username with password';
4. Copy the user name from id_rsa.pub file and paste it in username
   field;
5. Copy the private key from id_rsa file and paste it in
   'Private Key==> Enter directly'

It should work, try it.