# Why my git is not updating from 1.7.1 to 1.9.4

Tags: git

I am on REDHAT 6.
I want to update my git, I tried multiple ways.

**1st Method**

$yum update git.
I got : No Packages marked for Update.

**2nd Method**

```
$ wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.3.4.tar.gz
$ wget -O git-manpages-1.8.3.4.tar.gz http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-manpages-1.8.3.4.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Next, install all required libraries before building GIT:

$ sudo yum install zlib-devel perl-CPAN gettext

Now let’s untar and build and install GIT in the /usr directory:

$ tar xvfz git-1.8.3.4.tar.gz
$ cd git-1.8.3.4
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make prefix=/usr install
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.4
```

*Got This error.*

```
[qaserver@qaserver3 ~]$ cd git-1.8.3.4
[qaserver@qaserver3 git-1.8.3.4]$ ./configure
configure: Setting lib to 'lib' (the default)
configure: Will try -pthread then -lpthread to enable POSIX Threads.
configure: CHECKS for site configuration
configure: CHECKS for programs
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: in `/home/qaserver/git-1.8.3.4':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

**3rd Method**

*Install Required Packages*

```
 # yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
```

**Download and Compile Git Source**

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.9.4.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-1.9.4.tar.gz
```

**After downloading and extracting Git source code, Use following command to compile source code**

```
# cd git-1.9.4
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
# source /etc/bashrc
```

All the above command executed successfully without any error, but when i

```
$ git --version or $ git version
```

Still I m getting.

***git version 1.7.1***

I have gone mad, What is wrong with this any body have idea???

Comment: If you already have `git` on your path, then building a new version into `/usr/local/git/bin` and adding that to the END of the path will mean the old version is still found first...   try uninstalling git 1.7.1, or installing into /usr/local instead of /usr/local/git

Comment: use `which git` to see where the binary is located. Also, `bash` caches location of a binary so after uninstalling , either open a new shell or [see here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: The newer version is appended to the `PATH`. This means that the older version gets executed first. You should prepend `/usr/local/git/bin` in the `PATH`.

Comment: Use method 3, and just add removal of the installed git (yum remove git). I had the same issue with CentOS 6 and this solved it this way.

Comment: ok now the git 1.7.1 is UN-install. Could you please tell me how do i set the new git path

Comment: Same as you already did... echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc and source it. Test and let us know.

Comment: I'll add it as a formal answer for reference :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For RedHat or CentOS, method 3 is the right way to go, just need to remove the pre-existing git before:

```
yum remove git
```

After that, your new git will work as expected.

See [Install git on on CentOS/Redhat 7/6,5 and Fedora 22/21](http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/).

I hope this helps.